# Decryption Algorithm C++

Tags: c++, encryption

So i am trying to create an encryption/decryption program. I am encrypting by having the user enter a seed, then I use the seed provided to seed the random generator using srand(). I then create a list of numbers based on the seed, and use the numbers in sequence to apply a basic ceasar cipher on each induvisual character. The encrypt() function works fine, but when i try to decrypt, i don't get back the same text, Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <random>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int encrypt();
int decrypt();

int main() {
    int choice;
    bool quit = false;

    while (quit == false) {
        cout << "(1 Encrypt" << endl;
        cout << "(2 Decrypt" << endl;
        cout << "(3 Quit" << endl;

        cin >> choice;

        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            encrypt();
            break;
        case 2:
            decrypt();
            continue;
        case 3:
            quit = true;
            continue;
        default:
            cout << "Thats not a choice." << endl;
            continue;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int encrypt() {
//encryption method OK
    string input;
    int seed;
    char alphabeta[26] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };
    cout << "Enter the string you would like to encrypt in all lowercase: " << endl;
    cin >> input;
    cout << input << endl;
    //cout << endl;

    vector <int> randList;
    cout << input << endl;
    cout << "Enter your encryption seed: " << endl;
    cin >> seed;

    srand(seed);
    string outputStr;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        int tempRand = rand() % 26;
        randList.insert(randList.end(), tempRand);
        cout << tempRand << endl;
    }
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++) {
            if (input[i] == alphabeta[j]) {
                int j1 = j;
                if (j + randList[count] > 25) {
                    j1 = 0;
                }
                outputStr += alphabeta[j1 + randList[count]]; //+ randList[count]];
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "Here is your encrypted string :" << endl;
    cout << outputStr;
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}

int decrypt() {
//decryption method
    string input;
    int seed;
    char alphabeta[26] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };
    cout << "Enter the string you would like to decrypt in all lowercase: " << endl;
    cin >> input;
    cout << input << endl;
    //cout << endl;

    vector <int> randList;
    //cout << input << endl;
    cout << "Enter your encryption seed: " << endl;
    cin >> seed;

    srand(seed);
    string outputStr;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        int tempRand = rand() % 26;
        randList.insert(randList.end(), tempRand);
        //cout << tempRand << endl;
    }
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++) {
            if (input[i] == alphabeta[j]) {
                int j1 = j;
                //if (j - randList[count] <= 0) {
                    //j1 = 25;
                //}

                outputStr += alphabeta[j1 - randList[count]];
                if (j - randList[count] <= 0) {
                    j1 = 25;
                }
                cout << j1 - randList[count]<< endl;
                count++;

            }
        }
    }
    cout << "Here is your decrypted string :" << endl;
    cout << outputStr << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my decryption method:

```
int decrypt() {
    //decryption method
        string input;
        int seed;
        char alphabeta[26] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };
        cout << "Enter the string you would like to decrypt in all lowercase: " << endl;
        cin >> input;
        cout << input << endl;
        //cout << endl;

        vector <int> randList;
        //cout << input << endl;
        cout << "Enter your encryption seed: " << endl;
        cin >> seed;

        srand(seed);
        string outputStr;
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            int tempRand = rand() % 26;
            randList.insert(randList.end(), tempRand);
            //cout << tempRand << endl;
        }
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++) {
                if (input[i] == alphabeta[j]) {
                    int j1 = j;
                    //if (j - randList[count] <= 0) {
                        //j1 = 25;
                    //}

                    outputStr += alphabeta[j1 - randList[count]];
                    if (j - randList[count] <= 0) {
                        j1 = 25;
                    }
                    cout << j1 - randList[count]<< endl;
                    count++;

                }
            }
        }
        cout << "Here is your decrypted string :" << endl;
        cout << outputStr << endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Why is the decrypted result not matching the starting string before encryption?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through both the encryption *and* decryption functions in a debugger, to make sure they are working as expected?

Comment: Technically this is Off-Topic, you need to reduce this the core issue you are having - Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Yes, I did run them in a debugger.

Comment: and what did your debugging point to? where are the points in code that differ than what you expected, and how is it different? this is what @hoss is referring to.

Comment: My code runs, it's a logical error that i need to rectify.

Comment: This encryption method doesn't make any sense. You create random `randList` and you add it to input string. `randList` is not kept. Then you try to decrypt with a completely different random `randList`.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking a repeatable array of random numbers, adding them and later subtracting them, for example, if the input is 7 (after converting the character to the index) and the random number is 10, you encrypt:

7 + 10 = 17

and later, decrypt:

17 - 10 = 7

But in your logic, if the encrypt adds up greater than 25, you throw the input away. For example, if the input is 17:

17 + 10 = 27

But, 27 > 25, so...

0 + 10 = 10

You've lost the input forever. It will always "decrypt" to 0.

10 - 10 = 0

You'll end up with lots of 'a' in the output of decrypt, one for every input that you lost. Find another algorithm.

Comment: Ok, I think I see the error. I'll let you know wheather it works or not. It might take a week or so.